# TwinCAT 3 : Block stays busy

Tags: plc, st, twincat

I want to save some data into a .txt file. I can create it, but I can't write text into it because the FB stays busy.

```
    CASE counter OF
    1:
        fileOpen.sNetId := '';
        fileOpen.sPathName := 'C:\test\test.txt';
        fileOpen.nMode := FOPEN_MODEWRITE;
        fileOpen.bExecute := TRUE;
        fileOpen.tTimeout := T#200MS;

        fileOpen();

        counter := 2;
    2:
        IF NOT fileOpen.bBusy AND NOT fileOpen.bError THEN (* bBusy stays true*)
            counter := 3;
        END_IF
    3:
        fileOpen.bExecute := FALSE;
        fbPutFile(sNetId := '', hFile := fileOpen.hFile, sLine := 'FOO', bExecute := TRUE, tTimeout := INT_TO_TIME(200), bBusy =>, bError =>, nErrId =>);
     END_CASE
```

I get into step 2, but I can't get into step 3. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have stopped calling the function block for opening the file. What you're doing here is that you're calling the FB_FileOpen in step 1, but then stop calling it. The bBusy-flag goes high (true) in step1, but can never be changed to anything else as you never call the FB again. You need to make a call to it in step2 as well. Remember that bExecute is also a trigger for the ADS-command, so once you've done it in step 2, you can set the bExecute-input to FALSE in step2 and forward as you've already triggered the command.

```
...
2:
    fileOpen(bExecute := false);
    IF NOT fileOpen.bBusy AND NOT fileOpen.bError THEN (* bBusy stays true*)
        counter := 3;
    END_IF
...
```

Also remember that Beckhoffs FB_FileOpen assumes that the directory C:\test exists (though not the file test.txt if you open it with FOPEN_MODEWRITE it will be automatically created). To create all necessary directores (if they don't already exist) use TwinCATs FB_CreateDir.

Comment: Thank you, that's it! And I have to close the file to complete the action.